DioException (DioException [unknown]: null Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^ )
I am trying to get data from the server, but the server's response is like this:
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $response in <b>/home/sasansaf/techblog.sasansafari.com/Techblog/api/article/Model/ArticleModel.php</b> on line <b>191</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object,
null given in <b>/home/sasansaf/techblog.sasansafari.com/Techblog/api/article/Model/ArticleModel.php</b> on line <b>125</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $tags in <b>/home/sasansaf/techblog.sasansafari.com/Techblog/api/article/Model/ArticleModel.php</b> on line <b>175</b><br />
{
    "info": {
        "id": "19",
        "title": "فلاتر",
        "content": "من متن و بدنه اصلی مقاله هستم ، اگه میخوای من رو ویرایش کنی و یه مقاله جذاب بنویسی ، نوشته آبی رنگ بالا که نوشته \"ویرایش متن اصلی مقاله\" رو با انگشتت لمس کن تا وارد ویرایشگر بشی",
        "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20221218092957.jpg",
        "cat_id": "4",
        "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
        "author": null,
        "view": "7",
        "status": "0",
        "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۹/۲۷"
    },
    "isFavorite": false,
    "related": [
        {
            "id": "18",
            "title": "فلاتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20221218091728.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "11",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۹/۲۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "19",
            "title": "فلاتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20221218092957.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "7",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۹/۲۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "24",
            "title": "آموزش زبان انگلیسی",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20221219074227.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "6",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۹/۲۸"
        },
        {
            "id": "46",
            "title": "ابنجا عنوان مقاله قرار میگیره! پس یه عنوان جذاب انتخاب کن.",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230107133032.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "",
            "view": "2",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۱۰/۱۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "77",
            "title": "بروشورر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230315182040.instagram",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۱/۱۲/۲۴"
        },
        {
            "id": "88",
            "title": "uy",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230405035448.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱/۱۶"
        },
        {
            "id": "89",
            "title": "uy",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230405035545.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱/۱۶"
        },
        {
            "id": "90",
            "title": "uy",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230405035547.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱/۱۶"
        },
        {
            "id": "91",
            "title": "uy",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230405055919.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱/۱۶"
        },
        {
            "id": "120",
            "title": "اینجا عنوان مقاله قرار میگیره،یه عنوان جذاب انتخاب کن",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230608195254.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "1",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۳/۱۸"
        },
        {
            "id": "144",
            "title": "dsfsdfh",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230910063715.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "1",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۶/۱۹"
        },
        {
            "id": "150",
            "title": "تست عنوان",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230921155019.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "4",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۶/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "151",
            "title": "تست عنوان",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230921155110.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "2",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۶/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "154",
            "title": "عکس متن انگلیسی",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230922075402.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "4",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۶/۳۱"
        },
        {
            "id": "157",
            "title": "who?me?",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20230922091722.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "27",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۶/۳۱"
        },
        {
            "id": "164",
            "title": "yfgkb",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231001115409.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "1",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۷/۹"
        },
        {
            "id": "168",
            "title": "hguhf",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231001120959.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۷/۹"
        },
        {
            "id": "198",
            "title": "wewe",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231029145614.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "199",
            "title": "wewe",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231029145646.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "200",
            "title": "wewe",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231029145653.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۷"
        },
        {
            "id": "253",
            "title": "wewe",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231104190629.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "Ahmad",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۱۳"
        },
        {
            "id": "254",
            "title": "wewe",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231104190635.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "Ahmad",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۱۳"
        },
        {
            "id": "255",
            "title": "مفهوم  نوآوری باز",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231114102501.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "54",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۲۳"
        },
        {
            "id": "257",
            "title": "❤️ i mew you",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231116112751.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "9",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۲۵"
        },
        {
            "id": "259",
            "title": "مفهوم اکوسیستم کارآفرینی",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20231117191005.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "8",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۸/۲۶"
        },
        {
            "id": "317",
            "title": "کاراکتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240219061026.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "14",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱۱/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "318",
            "title": "کاراکتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240219062634.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "13",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱۱/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "319",
            "title": "کاراکتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240219062643.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "4",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱۱/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "320",
            "title": "کاراکتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240219062651.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱۱/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "321",
            "title": "کاراکتر",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240219062704.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۲/۱۱/۳۰"
        },
        {
            "id": "355",
            "title": "ماشین لرنینگ",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240502134120.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": null,
            "view": "2",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۳/۲/۱۳"
        },
        {
            "id": "381",
            "title": "آره بابا",
            "image": "/Techblog/assets/upload/images/article/20240520092835.jpg",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "cat_name": "سخت افزار",
            "author": "''",
            "view": "0",
            "status": "0",
            "created_at": "۱۴۰۳/۲/۳۱"
        }
    ],
    "tags": null
}

I don't have access to the backend developer to solve this problem, so how can I solve this problem with Flutter?

This is my piece of code in getting data from the server side

Future<dynamic> getMethod(String url) async {
    Dio dio = Dio();
    dio.options.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    var response= await dio
        .get(url,
            options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.json, method: 'Get'))
        .then((response) {
      //log(response.toString());
      return response;
    });
    
    return response;
  }

This is an error:

Exception has occurred.
-
DioException (DioException [unknown]: null Error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br /> ^ )



this is an error

Simply remove everything before first { to have valid JSON

And obviously response type is no longer a JSON, but rather plain text, parse it later

Change ResponseType.json to ResponseType.plain


You can add an interceptor to modify the returned data format so that you can get the json format inside. The following is a simple example. More adjustments and tests should be done in actual use.

dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onResponse: (response, handler) {
    String data = response.data.toString();
    final cleanedData = data.replaceAll(RegExp(r'<[^>]*>'), '').trim();
    try {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(cleanedData);
      response.data = jsonData;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to parse JSON: $e');
      response.data = {};
    }
    return handler.next(response);
  },
  onError: (DioException e, handler) {
    print('Request error: ${e.message}');
    return handler.next(e);
  },
));

